# CRM 2015 + Issue related to Translation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to translate some views in french in CRM 2015 Online so I did the following steps:

1. Created a solution, added the entity on which the view is created and    saved the solution.
2. Selected the solution and clicked Export Translation
3. After  export i get 2 files [Content_Types].xml and CrmTranslation.xml
4. However i could not locate my view in the CrmTranslation file
5. Views are basically "Accounts I Follow" "Contacts I Follow"

Any idea why these views are not present in the translation file?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

The CrmTranslation.xml can be opened in Excel. The labels can not easily be related to entities, attributes etc, because they are only specified by `Guid`s. Therefore your only option is to guess the location of the labels you need to translate.

Just add missing translations in Excel, save the file and import it in Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. however i can see all other views like "Active Accounts", it is only these views that are not present in the translation file.

Comment: Did you create them as system views or as user views?

Comment: i did not create them, they were there by default in the system.And they are system views

Comment: Try to delete the views and create them again. Maybe they show up in the translations then.